# How to change the Webview URL to another URL when failover

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In the Android Webview how can I change the webview url to another url when there is fail on the first url.

e.g.
I have 2 URL - url1 and url2

In the webview url load I put the url1

if in any case the url1 is down then my webview url should change to url2

Mainacivity.java

```
public void WebAction(){
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://url1");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        AppUpdateChecker appUpdateChecker=new AppUpdateChecker(this);
        appUpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(false); //mannual check false here
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public  void  onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String fallingUrl) {
                myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setTitle("Loading.....");
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setTitle(view.getTitle());
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the onReceviedErrorMethod

public  void  onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String fallingUrl) {
                myWebView.loadUrl("Put your second url");
            }

Comment: Thanks jawad, how If i would like to put the error.html if both the url are fail

Comment: Use a if statement and make a variable then checks whether the given url is the second url or not.

Comment: In this case if the user mobile does not have the internet connection that also it redirect to URL2. I want to redirect only when the user mobile has the internet connection and when the user mobile does not have internet connection it should display that his mobile has no internet.

Comment: Use connectivity manager to check whether the internet is connected or not. If yes then redirect to url2 and if not it will redirect to error page